# jQuery | Animate() issues in changing position of DIV

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-position

I am using `position:0px;` and `position:-135px;` to move a div up and down when someone hovers over it. I am using jQuery to animate the DIV so that it moves up on `onmouseover` and moves down on `onmouseout`.

Below is my jQuery code I have tried:

```
function show_slide_preview(id_to_preview){

    id_to_preview = "#" + id_to_preview;

    $(id_to_preview).animate({
        bottom: "0px",
    }, 1000 );
}

function show_slide_unpreview(id_to_preview){

    id_to_preview = "#" + id_to_preview;

    $(id_to_preview).animate({
        bottom: "-135px",
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Below is the HTML sample code:

```
<div class="slideshow_option_one_underlay" onmouseout="show_slide_unpreview('slide_1_button_preview');" onmouseover="show_slide_preview('slide_1_button_preview');" onclick="change_slide('slide_1');" id="slide_1_button">

        <img src="images/about_us_slider.png">

        <div class="slideshow_option_one slideshow_options" onclick="change_slide('slide_1')" id="slide_1_button_preview">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <p>Find out about our origins and what we can offer your business.</p>
            <a href="javascript:{}">Click Here To Read More</a>
        </div></div>
```

**The problem**

This actually works, however I get quiet a comical result because they keep bouncing up and down and dont stop!! Below is a GIF of it in action.

How do I solve this annoying yet funny bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be sure to call ".stop()" on the element to stop the current animation, this will keep the animations from becoming overly queued.

```
function show_slide_preview(id_to_preview){

id_to_preview = "#" + id_to_preview;

$(id_to_preview).stop().animate({
    bottom: "0px",
}, 1000 );}

function show_slide_unpreview(id_to_preview){
id_to_preview = "#" + id_to_preview;

$(id_to_preview).stop().animate({
    bottom: "-135px",
}, 1000 );}
```